# Puzzled by {% else %} not working in jinja template - (Mongodb cursor)

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I'm sending an aggregated cursor to a jinja template such as this (simplified here):

```
@app.route("/search")
def search():
    db_query = request.args["db_query"]
    results = mongo.db.perfumes.aggregate(
        [
            {"$match": {"$text": {"$search": db_query}}},
            {
                "$lookup": {
                    "from": "users",
                    "localField": "author",
                    "foreignField": "username",
                    "as": "creator",
                }
            },
            {"$unwind": "$creator"},
            {
                "$project": {
                    "_id": "$_id",
                    "perfumeName": "$name",
                    "perfumeBrand": "$brand",
                    "perfumeDescription": "$description",
                }
            },
            {"$sort": {"perfumeName": 1}},
        ]
    )
    return render_template("pages/perfumes.html", perfumes=results)
```

But the iteration over the cursor does something strange and the following in the template (also simplified here) doesn't work:

```
{% for perfume in perfumes %}
    {% if perfume %}
        {{ perfume }}
    {% else %}
        <h1>No Perfumes Matched your query</h1>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Meaning: `{{ perfume }}` displays well and it's the expected output based on the query, but I don't get the message in the `else`: "No Perfumes Matched your query" that I expect if the query didn't find any results.
I'm absolutely confused and cannot understand why if the `if` works the `else` doesn't...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are checking the wrong place

```
{% if perfumes %}
    {% for perfume in perfumes %}
        {% if perfume %}
        {{ perfume }}
        {% else %}
        {# the only way you will hit this is if you have a list of zeros or none #}
        <h1>No Perfumes Matched your query</h1>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
No Perfumes
{% endif %}
```

I think jinja provides a helper method for this in that you can attach your else to the iteration of perfumes

```
{% for perfume in perfumes %}
    {% if perfume %}
    {{ perfume }}
    {% endif %}
{% else %} 
    {# this else is attached to the for loop... not the if (maybe) #}
    <h1>No Perfumes Matched your query</h1>

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Ohhh I tried straight away with the second option and yes!!! Amazing, and I thought I had tried all the possible combinations!! Oh so many thanks for saving my day and sanity!!

Answer (score 0):

```
{% if perfumes is iterable %}
    value of variable: {{ perfumes }}
{% else %}
    variable is not iterable
{% endif %}
```

check perfumes states like @Joran Beasley